# Route external traffic from a standalone nginx service to kubernetes nodeport service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

**GOAL**
I want to get access to kubernetes dashboard with a standalone nginx service and a microk8s nodeport service.

**CONTEXT**
I have a linux server.
On this server, there are several running services such as:

- microk8s
- nginx (note: I am not using ingress, nginx service works independently from microk8s).

Here is the workflow that I am looking for:

1. http:// URL /dashboard
2. NGINX service (FROM http:// URL /dashboard TO nodeIpAddress:nodeport)
3. nodePort service
4. kubernetes dashboard service

**ISSUE:**
However, each time I request http:// URL /dashboard I receive a **502 bad request** answer, what I am missing?

**CONFIGURATION**
Please find below, nginx configuration, node port service configuration and the status of microk8s cluster:

[nginx configuration: /etc/nginx/site-availables/default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2i6p.png)

[node-port-service configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exeDh.png)

[node ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp27a.png)

[microk8s namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT5eb.png)

Thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: If you go manually at the dashboard NodePort endpoint, does it work?

Comment: when I execute: sudo microk8s kubectl get ep -n kube-system kimchi-nodeport-service > kimchi-nodeport-service  enpoint = <none> 
So I assume that you want me to use the cluster-ip of node port service instead of node ip. 
When I do it I receive an err_emtpy_response

Comment: Uhm, from the nginx configuration, everything is under path /dashboard, but maybe the kubernetes-dashboard expectes requests at / path. If that is the case, you could try with a rewrite-target in the nginx configuration?

Comment: nice try, I changed the location from /dashboard to /, but I still have the same behavior when I use node ip address or node port service cluster ip. Thank you for your time AndD

Comment: Can you check with a describe (or a get with option -oyaml) the kubernetes-dashboard service? To check if the Kubernetes Dashboard Pod is listening on 443 or on another port (with targetPort)

Comment: kubernetes dashboard description => TargetPort:8443/TCP, Endpoints:10.1.121.225:8443. I changed the configuration of kimchi nodeport service in order to target the port 8443. But I still receive 502 bad gateway

Comment: Other thing to check is the service selector. In order for your NodePort service to select the kubernetes-dashboard Pod, is your service selector equal to the one used by kubernetes-dashboard service? They should be the same as they want to select the same pod. Or as an alternative, check if your service is selecting the Pod by describing it (kubectl describe service <service-name>)

Comment: kubernetes dashboard pod description => Port:8443/TCP

Comment: Alright you fixed it (thank you for your precious help) the selector was wrong as you said I should have used k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard instead of app:kubernetes-dashboard. However as you said I can only display the dashboard using "/" in nginx configuration. I really need the "/dashboard" suffix. Are there any way to solve this issue? Maybe with some environment variables?

Comment: I added an answer which summarize everything and I tried answering your last doubt about the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the whole problem and solutions here.

First, the service which needs to expose the Kubernetes Dashboard needs to point at the right target port, and also needs to select the right Pod (the kubernetes-dashboard Pod)

If you check your service with a:

```
kubectl desribe service <service-name>
```

You can easily see if its selecting a Pod (or more than one) or nothing, by looking at the Endpoints section. In general, your service should have the same selector, port, targetPort and so on of the standard kubernetes-dashboard service (which expose the dashboard but only internally to the cluster)

Second, your NGINX configuration proxy the location /dashboard to the service, but the problem is that the kubernetes-dashboard Pod is expecting requests to reach / directly, so the path /dashboard means nothing to it.

To solve the second problem, there are a few ways, but they all lay in the NGINX configuration. If you read the documentation of the module proxy (aka http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) you can see that the solution is to add an URI in the configuration, something like this:

```
proxy_pass https://51.68.123.169:30000/
```

Notice the trailing slash, that is the URI, which means that the location matching the proxy rule is rewritten into /. This means that your_url/dashboard will just become your_url/

Without the trailing slash, your location is passed to the target as it is, since the target is only and endpoint.

If you need more complex URI changes, what you're searching is a rewrite rule (they support regex and lots more) but adding the trailing slash should solve your second problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed @AndD, you advice me to execute this command :

```
sudo microk8s kubectl describe service -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard
```

In order to get these below information

- Labels:k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
- TargetPort:8443/TCP

thanks to this above information, I could fix the nodePort service, you can find below a snippet:

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  k8s-app: 'kubernetes-dashboard'
ports:
 - protocol: TCP
  port: 8443
  targetPort: 8443
  nodePort: 30000
```

However, I did change the nginx configuration to

```
proxy_pass https://51.68.123.169:30000/
```

I do receive a successful response (html), then all remaining requests have a 404 status (js, css, assets).

[http 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axFH2.png)

---

## edit

the html file contains a set of dependencies (js/img/css)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3aaa4ab96be3c2d1171f.css"></head>
...
<script src="runtime.3e2867321ef71252064e.js" defer></script>
```

So it tries to get these assets with these URL:

- https::// URL/styles.3aaa4ab96be3c2d1171f.css
- https::// URL/runtime.3e2867321ef71252064e.js

instead of using:

- https::// URL/dashboard/styles.3aaa4ab96be3c2d1171f.css
- https::// URL/dashboard/runtime.3e2867321ef71252064e.js

## edit #2

I just changed again the subpath => dashboad/ to dash/

[new nginx conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POibN.png)

And it works with chromium.
But it doesn't with firefox. (not a big deal)

thank you very much AndD!

---

Besides, I got a similar issue with jenkins, however jenkins image contains a parameter that fixes the issue.
docker run --publish 8080:8080 **--env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/subpath"** jenkins/jenkins

I was expecting to find something similar with kubernetesui/dashboard but I haven't found anything
https://hub.docker.com/r/kubernetesui/dashboard

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

Well, I do not know how to configure very well nginx in order to display correctly the dashboard in a subpath and I didn't find any parameter in the kubernetes\dashboard image to handle the subpath.

Comment: Does it happens even if you serve the Kubernetes Dashboard under path /dashboard/ (with the trailing slash at the end) ? What is the path request for one of the 404 errors?

Comment: Hello, even dashboard under path /dashboard/ doesn't work. I just edited my message to explain the dependencies issue of the html file.